# ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES view has records with TABLE_OWNER AS NULL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES view has records with TABLE_OWNER AS NULL.

Why TABLE_OWNER is having NULL value and what is showing? Any privileges issues? Is this software bug?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: When you see the table in WebUI using databases/schema/table, what is the owner name shown there? Are you seeing the the value using Snowflake WebUI? Sharing screen shot will be easy.